# conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, jquery-ui, razor

I have the following model codes :

```
public class MyPartialViewModel1{
 public DateTime model1Date {get; set;};
     // other string properties
    }
 public class MyPartialViewModel2{
  public DateTime model2Date {get; set;}
 // other string properties
}
```

partial view for MyPartialViewModel1 is _MyPartialView1:

```
@model MyProjectNameSpace.MyPartialViewModel1
 <script type = "text/javascript">
  $('#model1Date').datepicker().bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
 </script>

@using (HTML.BeginForm("MyPartialView1PostToAction","MyController"))
{
   @HTML.TextBoxFor(model => model.model1Date)
//  other model properties razor code
 // also have a submit button for the form
}
```

partial view for MyPartialViewModel2 is _MyPartialView2:

```
 @model MyProjectNameSpace.MyPartialViewModel2
     <script type = "text/javascript">
      $('#model2Date').datepicker().bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 
            });
     </script>

    @using (HTML.BeginForm("MyPartialView2PostToAction","MyController"))
    {
       @HTML.TextBoxFor(model => model.model2Date)
    //  other model properties razor code
     // also have a submit button for the form
    }
```

Index view where both partial views used is (note: this view is not strongly typed against any model it just renders _MyPartialView1 and _MyPartialView2 along with few other partial views which doesnt have any Date Fields in their model properties)

```
@using(HTML.BeginForm("IndexPostToAction","MyController")){
@HTML.RenderAction("MyPartialView1Action")
@HTML.RenderAction("MyPartialView2Action")
// other partial views along with submit button
}
```

My controller code is as follows  :

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
   [ChildActionOnly]
   public ActionResult MyPartialView1Action()
   {
  return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/MyCustomFolder/_MyPartialView1"MyPartialViewModel1)
   }
[ChildActionOnly]
   public ActionResult MyPartialView2Action()
   {
  return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/MyCustomFolder/_MyPartialView2"MyPartialViewModel2)
   }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPartialView1PostToAction(MyPartialViewModel1 model)
  {
    // doing something
  }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPartialView2PostToAction(MyPartialViewModel2 model)
  {
    // doing something
  }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult IndexPostToAction(MyPartialViewModel1 model1,MyPartialViewModel2 model2)
  {
    // doing something
  }
}
```

Okay Now here is the problem I'm facing, *IndexView* postback is bringing me the exact *model1Date* which I've entered in the view using datepicker. But for *model2Date* at *IndexPostToAction()*, I'm getting "01/01/0001 00:00:00" although I entered different date valid date using datepicker and getting "conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value "

Here is some more info which you might be interested in:

- In *IndexView* page if I click submit button of *_MyPartialView2*, I'm getting correct *mode2Date* at *MyPartialView2PostToAction()*.
- In SSMS I verified the properties *model1Date* and *model2Date* are of *datetime* and *non nullable*
- using jQuery 2.0 +
- I could able to select date from *_MyPartialView2* in *IndexView* was not able get the same at *IndexPostToAction()*

Could you please help me in understanding, why I'm not getting exact *model2date* value from *IndexView* at *IndexPostToAction()* but *MyPartialView2PostToAction()* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes to get the exact value of *model2Date* at *IndexPostToAction()* :

changed the *_MyPartialView1* code to :

```
@model MyProjectNameSpace.MyPartialViewModel1

   @HTML.TextBoxFor(model => model.model1Date)
//  other model properties razor code
 // I REMOVED THE SUBMIT BUTTON,BEGINFORM AND SCRIPT CODE AND ADDED IT TO INDEX VIEW
```

changed *_MyPartialView2* code to :

```
@model MyProjectNameSpace.MyPartialViewModel2

 @HTML.TextBoxFor(model => model.model2Date)
    //  other model properties razor code
     // I REMOVED THE SUBMIT BUTTON,BEGINFORM AND SCRIPT CODE AND ADDED IT TO INDEX VIEW
```

changed my *IndexView* code to :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  $('#model1Date,#model2Date').datepicker().bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });
 </script>

@using(HTML.BeginForm("IndexPostToAction","MyController")){
@using(HTML.BeginForm("MyPartialView1PostToAction","MyController"))
{
// added _MyPartialView1 submit button here
@HTML.RenderAction("MyPartialView1Action")
}
@using(HTML.BeginForm("MyPartialView2PostToAction","MyController"))
{
// added _MyPartialView2 submit button here
@HTML.RenderAction("MyPartialView2Action")
}
// other partial views along with Index page submit button
}
```

With above changes in place i could get exact entered datepicker values from *IndexView* page. My guess is that because using begin forms, scripts code in the individual partial views resulted in some unexplained conflict.

Answer (score 0):

datetime2 can handle a wider range of dates than datetime, so converting to a smaller type will return that error. I would suggest changing your column to datetime2 in your database. It includes all posssible dates. Checkout this [Link](http://sqlhints.com/tag/datetime-vs-datetime2/). It shows you the difference between the two types.

Comment: I could do that @Dumisani, but my question is if I click submit button in _MyPartialView2 I get exact date value to MyPartialView2PostAction(), but if I submit using IndexView submit button to IndexPostToAction() I get exact value of model1Date but not model2Date which is "01/01/0001 00:00:00" I'm interested in why this behavior is happening ?